# Type python in Mobaxterm and nothing happens?

Tags: python, windows, unix, remote-access

I installed python in Mobaxterm by downloading the plugin and pasting it in the folder with the mobaxterm excutable.  Those were the instructions here:
http://mobaxterm.mobatek.net/plugins.html

When I navigate to my python folder in mobaxterm and type

```
python hello.py
```

nothing happens. The screen just sits there.

Before I installed python in mobaxterm, when I tried to run the above code, I got an error saying I need to install it.  I no longer get that error.

hello.py is just

```
print('hello')
```

Please help.

Comment: I had a similar issue with an older version (9.4) when it conflicts with the McAfee Anti-Virus as it blocks MobaSendMsg.exe.
Works with a newer version (11.1).